# Does Wake-on-LAN (WoL) depend on the motherboard or the network card?

Tags: motherboard, bios, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

This question was spurred by discovering the Acer M670G seems not have an Wake-on-LAN (WoL) settings in the BIOS and in general, wondering whether WoL is controlled by the BIOS/NIC or the OS.

One of my colleagues, “A” was discussing on the Wake-on-LAN (WoL)  functionality and mention that WOL depends on the motherboard and the BIOS settings.

Another colleague, “B” begs to differ. Colleague “B” think that if you have purchased and plugged in a PCI network card, the WoL functionality will then depend on the operating system as well as if the new internal PCI network card support WoL or not.

So should one say that the WoL functionality depends on the motherboard and the BIOS if the network card is embedded into the motherboard?

Also, can one assume that if one plugs in an internal PCI Network card onto the motherboard—regardless if the motherboard has existing embedded network card or not—the WoL functionality will now depend on the installed operating system and whether the network card has WoL functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Colleague “A” is 100% correct: Wake-on-LAN (WoL) functionality dependent on the motherboard and related BIOS settings. The NIC should be able to support WoL and the BIOS needs to be able to make sense of the NIC saying, “Hey! This is your NIC and my WoL has been triggered! Do you care do do something with this info, motherboard?”

As explained [very clearly on Wikipedia, Wake-on-LAN comes from the NIC’s firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Hardware_requirements) and is paid attention to by motherboards that respect WOL; bold emphasis is mine:

> **Wake-on-LAN support is implemented on the motherboard of a computer
>   and the network interface (firmware), and is consequently not
>   dependent on the operating system running on the hardware.** Some
>   operating systems can control Wake-on-LAN behaviour via NIC drivers.
>   With older motherboards, if the network interface is a plug-in card
>   rather than being integrated into the motherboard, the card may need
>   to be connected to the motherboard by an additional cable.
>   Motherboards with an embedded Ethernet controller which supports
>   Wake-on-LAN do not need a cable. The power supply must meet ATX 2.01
>   specifications.

And with more detail of how the BIOS plays into the whole setup; again bold emphasis is mine:

> **Wake-on-LAN usually needs to be enabled in the Power Management
>   section of a PC motherboard's BIOS setup utility, although on some
>   systems, such as Apple computers, it is enabled by default**. On older
>   systems the bios setting may be referred to as "WOL", on newer systems
>   supporting PCI version 2.2, it may be referred to as "PME" (Power
>   Management Events, which include WOL). It may also be necessary to
>   configure the computer to reserve standby power for the network card
>   when the system is shut down.

And even more details from [“How-To Geek Explains: What is Wake-on-LAN and How Do I Enable It?”](http://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/); yet again bold emphasis is mine:

> **WoL is dependent on two things: your motherboard and your network
>   card. Your motherboard must be hooked up to an ATX-compatible power
>   supply, as most computers in the past decade or so are. Your Ethernet
>   or wireless card must also support this functionality. Because it is
>   set either through the BIOS or through your NIC’s firmware, you don’t
>   need specific software to enable it.** Support for WoL is pretty
>   universal nowadays, even when it’s not advertised as a feature, so if
>   you have a computer built in the past decade or so you’re covered.

And on many modern systems, there is no explicit WoL setting in the BIOS with the functionality either given a different name or buried under other power settings [as explained in this Lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake-on-lan):

> To access your BIOS, restart your computer and press and hold the
>   Delete key (or whatever key your BIOS prompts you to hold) to enter
>   the BIOS setup. Once you're in the BIOS, head to the Power management
>   section and look for a Wake-on-LAN setting. If you find one, go ahead
>   and make sure it's enabled, then save and exit your BIOS and start up
>   your computer. **Not all BIOS will have a straight-up Wake-on-LAN
>   option, and on some boards you may have to enable a "Power On By PCI
>   Devices" setting. It varies from board to board, so a little trial and
>   error may be in order.**

Comment: If one can't find the WOL settings in the BIOS, may one assume that the machine do not support WOL even though it is build in the past decade or so and even the network card (regardless it is embedded onto the motherboard or a internal PCI network card) support this functionality?

Comment: actually my colleagues were discussing about the machine Acer M670G. They notice that it seems there is no options on WOL even though it is build in the past decade. That make them wonder if, in general, whether WOL depends on the motherboard or the network card.

Answer (score 1):

Great [answer from Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/898617/167207), thank you.

Just to sum up, the power supply must have a standby current available for when it is shut off, the network interface is still working (listening to the network) for WOL.

And the motherboard has to accept a signal from the network card (if integrated, it for sure is).

And finally, the WOL function must be enabled in the software/OS (Windows, perhaps), a small configuration in the network interface (yes, Windows may prevent this WOL event to start it up.